# webRTC works fine in Chrome, not on Firefox 18

Tags: firefox, webrtc

Okay, strange thing: somehow I can't get my webcam to work in Firefox 18 using webRTC. Even when I browse to a testing page like https://apprtc.appspot.com/ , it will work fine in Chrome, but Firefox won't even ask to use my camera.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem? I don't think posting code will matter much here, considering I'm experiencing it on every webRTC page.

Using Firefox 18 on OSX ML.

Comment: UPDATE: i enabled the media.navigator.enabled-flag. Now I always go to the error-callback though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, Firefox 18 does not yet support combining an audio and a videostream into a single stream. Requesting only the audio and/or videostream separately works fine.

Comment: **Note:** This has since been fixed (most likely in Firefox 20).